# Getting a list of all tables from the ReportServer Database

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportserver

Is there any way to get a list of all the tables in ReportServer database? I used the dbo.catalog to get all the reports. But I need to find a way where I can see all the tables that are being used in all the reports.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean tables in ReportServer database or tables used in the reports datasets (not from ReportServer)?

Comment: There really isn't a way to get a listing of all tables being used by your reports. There are just too many ways to get data into a report. You could be using dynamic sql, OpenQuery or even a link server as your datasource.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta I think, maybe, i want tables used in the reports datasets (from another server actually)

Comment: @SeanLange thanks, that makes sense

Comment: @NahidSultanaTithi, You can get the deployed datasets but for those datasets that are embeded in the reports you have to create a custom parser that reads each the RDL file, which implies a lot of work.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta Thanks, I am not that good with query writing. I will let my boss handle it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select * From [ReportServer$SS2014].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables
```